# Cannot delete Facebook some test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I call:

```
$ curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<APP_ID>/accounts/test-users?access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>&limit=500'
```

I see 82 accounts, and all but one look like this:

```
{
  "id": "1413484435585065",
  "login_url": "https://developers.facebook.com/checkpoint/test-user-login/1413484435585065/"
}
```

That is, they have no access token.

When I try to delete them I get:

```
$ curl -XDELETE 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1413484435585065?access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>'
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid value specified for param: id",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

The only one that DOES have an access token returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#2904) You cannot delete the Open Graph Test User for your app.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2904
  }
}
```

If I go to `Roles...Test Users` on the Developers page of the app, then it is empty!

Any new test users I create I can see on the Developers page, and I can delete them using the mentioned curl call.

Where could these test users come from, and how do I get rid of them? Or at least filter them when I am listing test users.

Comment: File a bug with Facebook

Comment: Yeah guess I will. Thanks.